# My Angular project isn't loading the scripts declared in the angular.json file

Tags: javascript, angular

**After running the project scripts declared in angular.json file are not loading**

```
 "scripts": [
             "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js",
              "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js",
              "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/app-info-parser.min.js",
              "node_modules/lz-string/libs/lz-string.min.js"
            ],
```

Tried to to re-install few library but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should add them under build architect

```
 "architect": {
   "build": {
     "options": {
        "scripts": []
```

After run the project,
they should be part of the scripts.js file.